# Using dates from an input file as min and max for slider input in shiny

Tags: r, date, shiny, slider

I have a shiny app in which I can load a file. I wan't to extract the min and max date range from  my file use these as input for a slider input.

Here is what I have so far

```
ui <- fluidPage(
dateRangeInput(inputId = "date", label = "Input a date range", start=textOutput("datemin") , end = textOutput("datemax"),"%d-%m-%y"))
)
server = function(input, output){
output$datemin <- renderText({as.character(as.Date(paste("01",as.character.Date(min(dataset()$date)),sep="-"),"%d-%y-%m"))})
     output$datemax <- renderText({as.character(as.Date(paste("01",as.character.Date(max(dataset()$date)),sep="-"),"%d-%y-%m"))})
}
```

I know the outputs datemin and datemax are a bit tricky,  this is because the "date" column in the dataset is a string such as "13-05" for may 2013 (the dataset is a summarized version with monthly means for some values)

Edit.

I've tried 3 different outputs for my date in order to check the format, and I display them as textoutput as follows :

UI

```
    textOutput("datemin1"),
    textOutput("datemin2"),
    textOutput("datemin3"),
```

Server

```
 output$datemin1 <- renderText({(as.character.Date(min(dataset()$date)))})
 output$datemin2 <- renderText({as.character(as.Date(paste("01",as.character.Date(min(dataset()$datem)),sep="-"),"%d-%y-%m"))})
 output$datemin3 <- reactive({as.Date(as.yearmon(min(dataset()$datem)))})
```

The outputs are the following :

> datemin1 : 14-01 
>  datemin2 : 2014-01-01 
>  datemin3 : 0014-01-01

But still when I try to use an output as an input value for my slider as follows :

```
    sliderInput("slider1", "Date Range",
                min = textOutput("datemin2"), max=textOutput("datemax2"),
                value = textOutput("datemax2")
    ),
```

I get this error :
ERROR: non-numeric argument to binary operator

Thanks

Comment: How do you want to show the date format on `sliderInput`? What is the complete date format in your dataset?

Comment: Originally the complete date format in the dataset is yyyy-mm-dd, but it is then dropped to yy-mm when the dataset is summarized to compute the monthly means of the data. On the sliderInput, the format can be mm-yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy with day initialized to 01 automatically.

Comment: Okay, please check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

`library(zoo)` includes `yearmon` which is a class for representing monthly data. Please see code below, it converts `13-05` to `13-05-01`.

```
library(shiny)
library(zoo)

dataset <- data.frame(minDate = c('13-05'), maxDate = c('14-05'))

if(interactive()){
  shinyApp(
    ui <- fluidPage(
      sliderInput("slider1", "Date Range",
                  min = as.Date(as.yearmon(dataset$minDate)),
                  max = as.Date(as.yearmon(dataset$maxDate)),
                  value = as.Date(as.yearmon(dataset$minDate))
                  )
      ),

    server = function(input, output){

      }
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution works fine, but still doesn't work when the date doesn't come from a standalone dataset as in your example. I added an edit to my question.